# React - How to set the value of many input controls that is built dynamically?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a component dynamically with many inputs, and I need to handle the onChange on these inputs...

So what I tired is to set a name for each input control and then on onChange call to set a state variable with the name of that control, and later on to use it from state to fill the "value" property of the input control  :

```
else if (element.Type === TEXT) {
                elements.push(
                    <td className="view-cell" align="left">
                        {element.Name}<br/>
                        <Input  key={element.Id}
                                name={element.Name.toLowerCase().replace(" ","")}
                                // label={element.Name}
                                // defaultValue={element.Value}
                                value={this.state.valueOf(element.Name.toLowerCase().replace(" ",""))}
                                disabled={!element.Editable}
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                    this.onInputValueChange(e)
                                }}
                        />
                    </td>
                )
            }



onInputValueChange(e) {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})

        console.log(this.state.valueOf(e.target.name))
}
```

But I can see that the state is not updated with the new values that I'm trying to add to it dynamically by the inputs names!

How can I achieve it?

## Update

When I try to access the state value from console I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: did you try this.state['header'] ? cuz this is the right way way to access an attribute in javascript or using this.state.header

Comment: if we want to add an object as a key for attribute we can use valueOf or the object itself like that this.state[object] , if it is a string then by the two ways mentioned above , if it is a number we can access it using this.state[number] -and that is how arrays are created btw-

Comment: Yes, you are right. That worked when printing the value to console (using Avanthika's solution) but when using it in the value property as bellow: value={this.state[inputName]}, the screen is still not reflected with the change... I guess it's because the async call to setState?!

Comment: one question you need to access the attribute or change the value of the attribute inside state ?

Comment: if that is the case then as easy as doing so this.setState({
    [yourVariable] : itsValue
  })

Comment: The behavior simply need to be: when the user change that input value, the value should appear inside the field... currently the field is empty and the text typed inside is not reflected to the screen?! so how can I make it work?

Comment: that's what I did, but it's still not reflecting the change on the screen

Comment: value={this.state[this.element.Name.toLowerCase().replace(" ","")]} add this instead of the value

Comment: cuz i tried it and it is working https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k8r7qc

Comment: I was using Input of ant design library, with react native input it works - you are correct.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed two things on your code:

1. You are trying to get the values from `valueOf` state variable. But you're missing to set the values in `valueOf` object in your onchange handler. If you add the missing bits, it should be fine.

   ```
   onInputValueChange(e) {
      this.setState({
       [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }, () => {
        console.log(this.state[e.target.name]);
        // use [] to access value instead of ()
      });
   }
   ```
2. Also, you have to access the values dynamically from an object by using square bracket [] notation.

   ```
   if (element.Type === TEXT) {
      const inputName = element.Name.toLowerCase().replace(" ","");
      elements.push(
       <td className="view-cell" align="left">
       {element.Name}<br/>
       <Input
         key={element.Id}
         name={inputName}
         label={element.Name}
         defaultValue={element.Value}
         value={this.state[inputName]}
         disabled={!element.Editable}
         onChange={this.onInputValueChange}
       />
     )
   }
   ```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 2 things: 1) it didn't compile with valueOf[e.target.name] on setState, so I used back [e.target.name] : e.target.value,  2) The change is still not reflected on the screen (might be related to 1 and the fact that I couldn't make it compile!)

Comment: Hi :) What library are you using?

Comment: antd for the Input element (https://ant.design/components/input/#header), doe's that make any change?!

Comment: with native react input it's working. just if you can edit your solution to use: this.state[inputName] (without any valueOf - not needed)